# Maximum upload size for Discord bots / webhook

Tags: node.js, file-upload, discord, discord.js, bots

I was planning about adding a ticket system in my discord bot that'll leave The whole conversation inside the ticket in a csv file. (In a specified Channel)

Now if the conversation gets long enough I'm afraid it might get bigger than 8mb (Non-nitro upload limit)

**So I was wondering if the upload limit is also applied to Bots or they have a different upload limit?**

Comment: Think of your bot as a regular Discord user. Just like a regular Discord user, he also has the same upload limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's 8mb
I figured it out thanks to **@Itamar**